# Spring unable to retrieve appContext

Tags: spring

How can you retrieve appContext in Spring? I've now tried several different ways and nothing works.

For example:

```
public class MapperTester {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    public MapperTester() {
        // appContext == null here :(
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your MapperTester class injected by Spring? if no then it wont work.

Comment: I'm trying to get a singleton instance of a Mapper class injected into other classes, like MapperTester. I thought I was supposed to do it by calling getBean from appContext in MapperTester. If MapperTester itself has to be injected, then this must be a wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing [ApplicationContextAware](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContextAware.html) should work but if you need to see details of why something isn't, then turn your logging level up to DEBUG for the `org.springframework` package (or possibly just the `.beans` or `.context` sub-packages).